# How do I tell TextFieldParser to parse from a provided filesystem?

Tags: c#, csv, textfieldparser

I'm writing a method which validates csv-files. I'm also unit-testing, so I'm setting up a mock file system with mock csv-files using `System.IO.Abstractions` I want to use `TextFieldParser` to read through the csv-file, but I'm unsure how I tell it to read from the path in the `IFileSystem` (from `System.IO.Abstractions`) provided.

Basically, the code looks something like this:

```
    internal static bool ValidateCsvFile(IFileSystem fileSystem, string path)
    {
        var validated = false;
        using (var csvReader = new TextFieldParser(path))
        {
            //validation
        }
    }
```

And I want to know how I essentially tell the `TextFieldParser` to parse from a path using the filesystem provided, instead of using the local computer.

Comment: What is the `path`? A path to the file or a (sub)directory or what else?

Comment: The path provided is a simple string of the path to the file on the mocked file system. It's just like a normal path (in my case, it's just "C:\testfiles\testfile1.csv"). However, I just now stumbled across a solution that worked for me. I'll post it now. It's just really annoying trying to find solutions using this package, because there's zero documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution myself. You have to set the using statement up like this:

```
        using (var csvReader = new TextFieldParser(fileSystem.FileInfo.FromFileName(path).OpenRead()))
```

This will let you read from the file in the mocked filesystem, or the local filesystem if you're running the program normally and it calls on a separate public method that calls on this using a `new FileSystem` (from `system.io.abstractions`). Basically like this:

```
    public static bool ValidateCsvFile(string path)
    {
        return ValidateCsvFile(new FileSystem(), path);
    }
```

Assuming a `using System.IO.Abstractions` in the .cs-file and no package conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main rules of unit testing is it shouldn't ready any external files. I can understand you are trying to read mock file but that is still a file, it means your unit test is trying to read an external file which is a dependency and should be avoided.

Comment: The unit test sets up the file structure and file content completely. There's no external influence on it. The unit test itself does not read the file. The method it passes the file structure to, does (just like it'd read the local file structure when called normally).